# Undefined property after passing an object as a parameter

Tags: javascript

```
function foo() {
    bar = 'ok';
    new baz( this );
}

function baz( foo ) {
    alert( foo.bar );
}

new foo();
```

Why is it that the alert shows "undefined" instead of "ok"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bar` has gone out of scope. [There is a difference between scope and context](http://clubajax.org/javascript-scope-and-context-not-the-same-thing/). if you want to attach a property to `foo`, you must [attach the property to the function](http://jsfiddle.net/Luy8C/).

```
function foo() {
     this.bar = 'ok';
     new baz(this);
    }

function baz(foo) {
    alert(foo.bar);
    }

new foo();​
```

Answer (score 2):

Its because foo.bar is a private variable. Change it to this and it'll work

```
function foo() {
    this.bar = 'ok';
    new baz(this);
    }

function baz(foo) {
    alert(foo.bar);
    }

new foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because variables are not properties *(except WRT global variables/properties)*. You're creating a global variable `bar` by not using the `var` statement. Even if you use `var`, it doesn't show up on the object being constructed.

Since you're using `new`, you can set the property on `this`.

```
this.bar = "ok"
```

So full code is...

```
function foo() {
    this.bar = 'ok';
    new baz(this);
    }

function baz(foo) {
    alert(foo.bar);
    }

new foo();
```

---

By the way, the `new` keyword is wasted on `baz` since you're not retaining any object created.

Comment: @Alnitak: Yeah, good point. I'll add that clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your `baz` function `foo` is not being passed as a reference, it's a placeholder for a parameter. When you do `new foo` you're using `foo` as a constructor. `bar` is global since it hasn't been declared with `var` or `this.bar`. I think you need to revisit the basics, this question is too wrong...

Comment: Yea maybe I should, but I come from PHP, today is my second day coding in JavaScript. Thanks.